# Renaming/Deleting User Subfolders (Documents, Pictures...)

Tags: terminal, finder, user-account, macos

I want to move my User/{Documents, Downloads, Movies, Music, Pictures} folders to an external SSD. I will do this via copying the folders to the SSD, and creating symlinks on User/ to each of them. For this I need to rename the original folders and later delete them.

I have tried via Finder, terminal (sudo), Apple Support, however I see no way to either delete them nor rename them.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Is this in Mojave?

Comment: Yes, it’s Mojave